# Premium heated bed upgrade options?

Tags: heated-bed, diy-3d-printer, bed-leveling

The stock heated bed which came on my Creality printer is significantly warped beyond any simple leveling with the screws. Lets say I want to upgrade the stock bed to a premium heated bed, does such a thing even exist? None of the beds I see list any specs or tolerances regarding flatness or deviation.

What should I be looking for to ensure I am looking at a superior bed?

Comment: I have an ender 3, my heating bed is working perfectly fine. We don't endorse in bashing, we don't endorse in product recommendations as those are not allowed as per stack policy.

Comment: +1   I have the same problem and am looking at junking my whole CR10 as a result; any cheaper suggestion/solution would be welcome.

Comment: How about an aluminium heated bed? This might be a useful question for you, although it doesn't deal with warping directly, [Do aluminium PCB heatbeds reduce hotspots?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3103/do-aluminium-pcb-heatbeds-reduce-hotspots) I could turn this comment into an answer, if it is useful and relevant...

Answer (score 1):

If you are only trying to upgrade the "flatness" of the bed and are okay with the heating times you can just put a peice of glass on top. Otherwise you can look into getting a milled tool plate which will be much flatter than a rolled or stamped plate, but you will have to attach your own heating element to this.

Comment: also note that a milled plate is usually a custom ordered part and can be quite expensive, especially if you want to use a really good heat conductor. Copper is about twice as good as aluminium, Steel about half as good (but cheaper)

Comment: My creality printer came with glass. warped. Flipping the glass upside-down helped slightly, but 
wasn't great.  I tried replacing with a 12" mirrored tile, but the metal bed that the glass attaches to is slightly convex (+/- 0.35mm), so when you clamp down the glass to achieve good heat transfer, it bends any glass on the bed.

Comment: @davdavis what are you clamping the glass down with?